# Firebase debugging tools

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-storage

Is there any way to debug firebase instance like number of reads / writes / live connections etc.

We have hit the firebase outage many times and it is only firebase support tell us about these metrics.

Are there tools available which if I run on instance let me know all above information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Firebase Profiler tool](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) to get an idea of your bandwidth consumption but as stated by the doc, it's not a tool to estimate your billing. Many other factors affect your billing, such as protocol overhead, ssh overhead etc. You can read more on the [Understand Realtime Database Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) here.

The Firebase profiler can however helps you to see potential issues with your database, and potential heavy listeners that sync too many data. Keep in mind that **every** time you write a `on` listener, firebase will download all the initial data at this node, each time, thus increasing bandwidth usage.

Comment: Thanks .. One more thing - I was running a very read heavy script on firebase and later I realize it has bring down whole instance. Connections to it are very slow . my question is how can I restart OR release the locked resource , assuming I have stopped the faulty script. As of now I have to contact firebase support and get it done which takes ages .